# making best_in_place input look like bootstrap input

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, best-in-place

Currently and defaultly, best_in_place works as

before edit

[image]

once in edit mode it looks like

[image]

What I would like is that the before edit would like like a regular (vanilla) bootstrap input

[image]

and in edit mode it would look like editting a regular input box

unfortunatly, all my attempts of combining css and javascript have failed..

I cannot set the engulfing div as .form-control since it will look like 
[image]

I couldn't figure out what event to listen to when clicking on the field (focus/blur didn't work.. click works but then I need a click away type event (is there such an event)
listening on the change event would only work when the field is changed, but when it is clicked yet not changed it would misbehave

This is a jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/E8W4X/5/ to simulate the before edit (.form-control with the text) and the edit mode (a form is automatically injected into div.form-control)

the fiddle has the best_in_place javascript

edit mode in the fiddle is what happens when you click on Tim

What I would like is it to look like the input box in "desired styling" which is basically a normal input box

and here is a html from the jsfiddle

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-2">
        <div class="panel">
            <fieldset>
                <div class="form-group">
                      <label>before edit mode</label>
                    <div class="form-control">
                        Tim
                    </div>


                    <label>edit mode</label>
                    <div class="form-control">
                        <form class="form_in_place" action="javascript:void(0);" style="display:inline">
                            <input type="text" name="first_name">
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </fieldset>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: For some reason I am still not able to understand what you want. What actually do you mean by edit mode ?

Comment: By any chance is this what you are looking for ?http://jsfiddle.net/E8W4X/2/

Comment: see the updated fiddle, which behaves the same as best_in_place http://jsfiddle.net/E8W4X/5/

Comment: Did you check the answer I gave ?

Comment: @NickGinanto I have provided an answer that does not require javascript.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not need JavaScript or new CSS classes to solve this. The gem [supports additional attributes to the options hash](https://github.com/bernat/best_in_place#best_in_place). You want to add `:inner_class` to change the class of the form field. Bootstrap uses the CSS class `.form-control` to apply its custom look.

My solution will be in HAML, but you can also so the same in ERB or SLIM.

```
= best_in_place @user, :name, type: :input, inner_class: 'form-control'
```

[You can even apply attributes globally to all bip form fields.](https://github.com/bernat/best_in_place#configuration)

Answer (score 2):

Okay so FINALLY I managed it.

So look what I did was searched for where it created input box and added class form-control to it @ line# 317

```
output.parents('div.form-control').removeClass('form-control');
```

and added it back before the blur @ line#336

event.target.closest('div').addClass('form-control');

```
jQuery(event.target).closest('div').addClass('form-control');
```

Here is the **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/E8W4X/8/)**

Comment: I forgot event.target was an html object not a jquery object. All fine now. FYI you can edit and do the same for other inputs also.

Comment: This does work, but this changes the source of the plug-in. Is there a way to do this without changing the source?

Comment: Nope. There is no other solution that I can think of which doesn't require changing the source code. But if you notice, I just changed the appearance of the inputs. Not even the html structure. You mind telling, what's keeping you from using it ?

Comment: best_in_place is a ruby gem which is not maintained by me, if I change the code, I will have to maintain my own separate version for any future updates. I was hoping it is possible to alter the behavior using css/js from outside of the plugin source

Comment: Well, then you'd have to add custom event listeners which listen to bestinplace's "input" creation and "blur" events and add the code yourself.